# display inline checkbox using bootstrap in a table by limiting the no of cells

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<?php
while ($deityQueryResult = mysqli_fetch_array($deityQueryData)) {
    echo '<td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="' . $deityQueryResult['deityName'] . '">' . $deityQueryResult['deityName'] . '</label></td>';
}                                                                       
?></tr></table>
```

Is it possible to limit the no of cells in a table to 4 and then create a new row after that? Basically I am trying to display the data in a box format. Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of cells in each row, what you are actually want to say is that after X cells - you want to close the current row and create a new one.

In order to do that you will need a new variable to count the `current` cell you are in, and based on that number you will decide if to create a new row or not.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<?php
$i = 0;
$MAX_PER_ROW = 4;

while ($deityQueryResult = mysqli_fetch_array($deityQueryData)) {
    echo '<td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="' . htmlspecialchars($deityQueryResult['deityName']) . '">' . $deityQueryResult['deityName'] . '</label></td>' . "\n";
    $i++;
    if ($i % $MAX_PER_ROW == 0) {
        echo "</tr><tr>\n";
    }
}
?></tr></table>
```

> Note the use of the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) `$i % $MAX_PER_ROW`